# Android UDP troubles

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm working on a small project for learning purposes , consisting of two instances of clients and a server instance .
The server and one of the clients are running on my PC whose code is written in Java , while the 2nd client runs on android .

The server is listening on a given port. When the Java client sends a packet to the server , it retains the IP / port to send in response to a future packet received from the android terminal , and vice versa.

Communications between each client and server working properly. But when communicating between clients ( assuming each acquired the ip / port on the other , as a response from the server) nothing comes to android terminal.

In both instances of the client, the socket is created as :

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket ();
```

Then contact the server only once , to store my address data :

```
Socket.Send ( sendPacket ) ;
```

( SendPacket is instantiated with fixed data server)

And then instantiate the listen method , passing as parameter one datagram packet containing only the number of bytes to receive.

```
socket.receive (packet );
```

Implementing this method in an infinite loop , I've only managed to receive packets from the server ( the answers ) and not the other client application.

The permissions in the manifest I use are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I appreciate any tip . Thank you very much !

Comment: Did you get a multicast lock on the android device?

Comment: No, i'm trying to work with mobile network. The server forwarding (in my LAN) is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented two socket one for send and another for receiving and is working for me whit some modifications attending to my needs. I am assuming you are forgetting the port ... or something... put a log of your error or more code to help you... 
Below is the code working for me

```
    int port =1515;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //////send socket
    int eport = 1616;
    InetAddress eip = null;
    try {
        eip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1");  ////SERVER IP ADDRESS ---- Server comunication is working so I assume you have it
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    DatagramSocket esocket = null;
    try {
        esocket = new DatagramSocket(eport);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


//////Start receive
    while(true)
    {


        byte[] message = new byte[60*1024];
        DatagramPacket recv_packet = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);


        try {
            socket.receive(recv_packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    ///Do something whit recv_packet
}
```